# MS Teams alert, triggered via webhook and PS script, does not want to parse the text on multiple lines

Tags: json, powershell, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a PS script that is supposed to post MS Teams alerts via webhooks, regarding some metrics. The current solution that I have almost made work is via a PSCustomObject, which is afterwards converted to JSON and used as the body of the alert. The below is the current code that I am using:

```
$JSONBody = [PSCustomObject][Ordered] @{
     "@type"     = "MessageCard"
     "title"     = "Alert Title"
     "text"      = "Alert 1: $alert1CountVariable
                    Alert 2: $alert2CountVariable
                    Alert 3: $alert3CountVariable"
}

$TeamsMessageBody = ConvertTo-Json $JSONBody -Depth 100

$parameters = @{
    "URI"          = '<Teams Webhook URI>'
    "Method"       = 'POST'
    "Body"         = $TeamsMessageBody
    "ContentType"  = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod @parameters
```

Everything works as needed, but as you can see the text parameter within the PSCustomObject is supposed to parse the 3 alerts on 3 separate lines, which does not seem to happen whatever I try. I tried inserting the \n and \r operators (also tried \n and \r) and nothing works this far.

Another working method that I have is the following:

```
$Body = '{"text": "Alert 1: ' + $alert1CountVariable +' Alert 2: ' + $alert2CountVariable +' Alert 3: ' + $alert3CountVariable +'"}'
$TeamsUrl = '<Teams Webhook URI>'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $TeamsUrl -Method Post -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json"
```

However, this also does not fully satisfy the criteria, as it still does not display the alets on separate lines and there is no title here.

Any advise on how I can make any of these two options work?

Comment: Have you tried with `r and `n ? \r and \n are java/script notation, not PowerShell

Comment: Arg! Stack Overflow markdown is killing my comment. Basically, you need 'backtick', like this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-new-lines-with-powershell/

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, use `\ ` to escape backticks in comments.

Comment: You don't need to cast `[ordered]` to `[pscustomobject]`, it's already implied

Comment: I have removed the [ordered] yes. Also, I have tried all variations of \r and \n, including with the backtick and I have tried escaping them with \. I think it is the correct syntax for PS but the problem comes from the conversion to JSON. Anyways, oddly enough the <br> seems to solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the problem is unrelated to JSON, whose encoding and decoding correctly passes embedded newlines through (escaped as `\n`). Instead, as the accepted answer shows, alert text is seemingly expected to be HTML, where literal newlines are ignored, and `<br>` is needed to effect a line break for display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The teams interface seems to accept HTML:

Please see your script adjusted below:

```
$JSONBody = [PSCustomObject][Ordered] @{
     "@type"     = "MessageCard"
     "title"     = "Alert Title"
     "text"      = "Alert 1: $alert1CountVariable <br>
                    Alert 2: $alert2CountVariable <br>
                    Alert 3: $alert3CountVariable"
}

$TeamsMessageBody = ConvertTo-Json $JSONBody -Depth 100

$parameters = @{
    "URI"          = '<Teams Webhook URI>'
    "Method"       = 'POST'
    "Body"         = $TeamsMessageBody
    "ContentType"  = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod @parameters
```

I have inserted `<br>` at the end of each line which is a line break in HTML.